# PHP if not empty row do update else insert

Tags: php, mysqli

what is a problem with this code. I cannot go into insert function if table is empty, it is always doing update. Can anyone help me to solve this thing?

```
  while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

               $updatequery = sprintf("UPDATE stat_mailings SET cat_id='%s', mailing_name='%s', mailing_unique_id='%s', segment_id='%s', 
                                                                        campaign_id='%s', landing_page='%s', total_sent='%s' WHERE mailing_id='%s'",
                                        $row->category_id,
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->mailing_naam),
                                        $row->unique_id,
                                        $row->mailing_segment,
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->utm_campaign),
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->landing_page),
                                        $row->mailing_total_sent, 
                                        $row->id                                           
                );

                 $mysqli->query($updatequery);
                 echo $error = $mysqli->error;   


        } else {

           $insertquery = sprintf("INSERT INTO stat_mailings SET mailing_id='%s', cat_id='%s', mailing_name='%s', mailing_unique_id='%s', segment_id='%s', 
                                                                        campaign_id='%s', landing_page='%s', total_sent='%s'",
                                        $row->id,
                                        $row->category_id,
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->mailing_naam),
                                        $row->unique_id,
                                        $row->mailing_segment,
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->utm_campaign),
                                        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row->landing_page),
                                        $row->mailing_total_sent                                                                                       
                );

                 $mysqli->query($insertquery);
                 echo $error = $mysqli->error;      

        }
```

Comment: $result->num_rows is always greater than 0 .Check the value of $result->num_rows

Comment: Yup, i know that, but how to solve this, that it will work ? I cant figure it out ..

Comment: As I said check the values. your query always returnes more than 0 rows and the code does not get into insert part

Comment: Remove while loop and try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mysql has great feature exactly for this purpose - ON DUPLICATE query.
It looks like

```
INSERT INTO t SET f1=val,f2=val2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE f1=val,f2=val2
```

and so on.
Only make sure you have an UNIQUE index on the key field.
So, you can get rid of your SELECT query and it's result checking.